"Отдать в плечо" translation
I've found a phrase винтовка отдала в плечо. Why is в плечо in this phrase? Is it part of an idiom or does it actually mean "the rifle recoiled into his shoulder"? This may be an obvious question, but I'm going through the first 1000 words by frequency.

Hi and welcome to Russian SE! The way it's stated now, it is an obvious question. Is there a reason you think that expression wouldn't mean "recoil into the shoulder" (as it does)? If yes, please specify it. Thank you!
